# How to save the build time of a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

My project is a C++ DLL (cmake project), that expose methods from a c interface to another C# project,
I want to add a methode getBuildTime() in the c interface that return the buildtime (the exact date and time) so from the C# project we can know when the DLL was built.
Is there a way to do this stuff ?
I don't know if this useful or no but I'm using git as a version control system

Comment: One consideration is do you want it to always set a new date even if nothing in the dll has changed. I used to worry about this, then I eventually moved to use the source control revision as part of my version string instead of the date/time.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, the most important is that the user (the C# application) can know when the dll was built last time  (in the next step I need to give the user also the git version and some other informations like the version.. )

Comment: I'm not familiar with this stuff I looked at google and I'm still confused, what I need to do is to versioning the project ( I found some stuff about this on stackoverflow ) and also to give the user the ability to see the version/buildtime/gitversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build time in C/C++ code can be obtained by built-in macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`, e.g. do something like `string build_time = __DATE__ " " __TIME__;`.

Also file which contains these macros usage needs to be `touch`ed before each build to change file's modify time. [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(command)) is a unix command, which can be avaialble in Windows too through [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or other means. This is needed to force it to recompile to use new date. Do file touching by adding `touch build_time.cpp` command to Pre-Build Events, they should be located in your project config somewhere. Alternatively you may add `touch`ing to your make file. Altertnatively some compile environments and possibly MSVC too can configure which files to rebuild always which is tweaked inside project's settings.

Also if you use `git` version control system then you might want to use last git commit hash and time together or instead of build time above. Git commit hash and time is sometimes better than to use build time like suggested above, because git hash and time remain same on each re-compile before next commit, this ensures that your DLL build time changes only when code changes/committed, this may help to have reproducible DLL compiles. To support git hash and time do next things:

If you have unix `echo` and `bash` and `git` commands in your system e.g. by installing [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or new native Windows SubSystem for Linux then you may do next things in command script `before_build.cmd` that you run before build, also this shell script can be run on Unix systems almost without modifications:

```
linux_echo -n "" > cfg.h

linux_echo -n "#define GIT_COMMIT """ >> cfg.h
linux_bash -c "echo -n $(git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD)" >> cfg.h
linux_echo """" >> cfg.h

linux_echo -n "#define GIT_COMMIT_TIME """ >> cfg.h
linux_bash -c "echo -n $(git show -s --format=%%ci $(git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD) | tr -d '\n')" >> cfg.h
linux_echo """" >> cfg.h

linux_echo -n "#define COMPILE_TIME """ >> cfg.h
linux_bash -c 'echo -n $(date +"%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S %%z")' >> cfg.h
linux_echo """" >> cfg.h
```

and you will get `cfg.h` like:

```
#define GIT_COMMIT "fe0a7891"
#define GIT_COMMIT_TIME "2020-05-13 17:42:55 +0100"
#define COMPILE_TIME "2020-05-13 18:20:28 +0100"
```

these config file and macros you can use in your code.

Comment: `touch` is a hack, if you're going to modify the build to perform a `touch` it would be better to just use the proper method of marking the task always out-of-date... then you only affect build order and not also version control, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt Version control like `git` will not show this file as modified if it is touched, tested. So you don't need to commit it each time.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ preprocessor predefines several macros (backward compatible with C) including `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.  These expand to string literals containing the date and time of the build (in particular, the date and time that the preprocessor runs on that particular file).

You may need to force the compilation unit containing them to be rebuilt on every change.  With `make` that can be done with `.PHONY`, with cmake it looks like [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) is the ticket.

> Add a target with no output so it will always be built.

---

Besides using `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` to capture when the compiler ran, the linker will store a timestamp in the PE header of the DLL it creates.  There's no configuration necessary to make this happen, but then you have to write code to read the PE header and convert the timestamp to your favorite date and time format.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor solution is way simpler, but the following approach may be convenient, if you need to provide other properties of the build system as well.

Create a cmake script file that generates a source file. Use this script to generate the source file providing the info:

**generate_timestamp.cmake**

```
#parameter: OUTPUT_FILE
string(TIMESTAMP _TIMESTAMP "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
file(WRITE ${OUTPUT_FILE} "#include \"buildtime.h\"
const char* getBuildTime() {
    return \"${_TIMESTAMP}\";
}")
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(_BUILD_TIME_FILE buildtime.cpp)

add_library(mylib ${_BUILD_TIME_FILE} ...)
set_source_files_properties(${_BUILD_TIME_FILE} PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)

get_filename_component(_BUILD_TIME_FILE_ABSOLUTE ${_BUILD_TIME_FILE} ABSOLUTE)

# generate source using cmake script file
add_custom_target(buildtime_info COMMAND "${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL}" -D "OUTPUT_FILE=${_BUILD_TIME_FILE_ABSOLUTE}" -P generate_timestamp.cmake)

# generate file before building mylib
add_dependencies(mylib buildtime_info)
```